# Replace words in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have words against their synonyms. In the different data frame, I have sentences. I want to search synonyms from the other dataframe. If found, replace it with word for which synomym found.

```
dt = read.table(header = TRUE, 
text ="Word Synonyms
Use 'employ, utilize, exhaust, spend, expend, consume, exercise'
Come    'advance, approach, arrive, near, reach'
Go  'depart, disappear, fade, move, proceed, recede, travel'
Run 'dash, escape, elope, flee, hasten, hurry, race, rush, speed, sprint'
Hurry   'rush, run, speed, race, hasten, urge, accelerate, bustle'
Hide    'conceal, cover, mask, cloak, camouflage, screen, shroud, veil'
", stringsAsFactors= F)


   mydf = read.table(header = TRUE, , stringsAsFactors= F,
                    text ="sentence
    'I can utilize this file'
    'I can cover these things'
    ")
```

The desired output looks like -

```
I can Use this file
I can Hide these things
```

Above is just a sample. In my real dataset, I have more than 10000 sentences.

Comment: What would you want as result if you have one word which matches multiple results? Or is that not occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can replace `,` in `dt$Synonyms` with `|` so that it can be used as `pattern` argument of `gsub`. Now, use `dt$Synonyms` as pattern and replace occurrence of any word (separated by `|`) with `dt$word`.  One can use `sapply` and `gsub` as:

**Edited:** Added word-boundary check (as part of pattern in `gsub`) as suggested by OP.

```
# First replace `, ` with `|` in dt$Synonyms. Now dt$Synonyms can be
# used 'pattern' argument of `gsub`.
dt$Synonyms <- paste("\\b",gsub(", ","\\\\b|\\\\b",dt$Synonyms),"\\b", sep = "")

# Loop through each row of 'dt' to replace Synonyms with word using sapply
mydf$sentence <- sapply(mydf$sentence, function(x){
  for(row in 1:nrow(dt)){
    x = gsub(dt$Synonyms[row],dt$Word[row], x)
  }
  x
})

mydf
#                  sentence
# 1     I can Use this file
# 2 I can Hide these things
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can we also add regex pattern \\b that checks the whole word (word boundary)?

Comment: Yes. You should. Otherwise it will replace part of the word. Good point.

Comment: @john Updated it. One can add word-boundary by `strsplit` and then `collapse`. But my answer worked on sample data in question since `Synonyms` are evenly spaced with `, `.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution...

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>% 
  mutate(Synonyms=str_split(Synonyms, ",\\s*")) %>% #split into words
  unnest(Synonyms) #this results in a long dataframe of words and synonyms

mydf2 <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(Synonyms=str_split(sentence, "\\s+")) %>% #split into words
  unnest(Synonyms) %>% #expand to long form, one word per row
  left_join(dt2) %>% #match synonyms
  mutate(Word=ifelse(is.na(Word), Synonyms, Word)) %>% #keep unmatched words the same
  group_by(sentence) %>% 
  summarise(sentence2=paste(Word, collapse=" ")) #reconstruct sentences

mydf2

  sentence                 sentence2              
  <chr>                    <chr>                  
1 I can cover these things I can Hide these things
2 I can utilize this file  I can Use this file
```